# Mac Excel 2011 Userform

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2011

Is there a way to perpetually display a button-click userform on the spreadsheet for Mac Excel? I know the Windows version is capable of such a command. I've tried

```
Userform.show
Unload Userform
```

This code displays the userform, however, once it shows up you are disallowed from using the Excel spreadsheets.

Comment: Can't say for sure about Mac, but on Windows you can use `Userform.show vbModeless`